# Go high, go bye, go die

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> STEAL my prefix and go high.
> STEAL my suffix and go bye.
> STEAL my infix and go die.
> Leave me be and go STEAL!

> *<sub>One homophone alert in effect.</sub>*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer might be:

> **SHOPLIFT**

*STEAL my prefix and go high.*

> Remove ('steal') 'SHOP' to leave **LIFT** (i.e. raise up *high*).

*STEAL my suffix and go bye.*

> Remove 'LIFT' to leave **SHOP**, meaning 'buy' - a homophone of '*bye*' (acceptable as per the OP's fair warning in their post).

*STEAL my infix and go die.*

> Remove 'PLIF' and you have been **SHOT** (and might *die*...).

*Leave me be and go STEAL!*

> Leave the word intact: **SHOPLIFT** means to *go out and steal* from a store...

Comment: rot13("Fb gur ubzbalz jnfa'g 'tb fgrny' -> 'tubfg rry' nsgre nyy!")